# How to show full height of a background image in a one page layout?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to show the full background image as a landing page, then the content appears when the user scrolls down, however the bottom of the background image is usually cut off (depending on browser resolution).

I'm trying:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Here is a codepen that demonstrates the issues:

https://codepen.io/suez/full/wulBv/

You can see that the bottom of the first image with Iron Man is cut off. Here is the full image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFSWf.jpg).

Is there a way to show the full height of an image? Even if you need to scroll down more to see it?

Answer (score 2):

use css:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: but this will distort the image (i.e. its width/height proportions)

Comment: ya thats true you can use other tricks like https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `background-position: bottom`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMMVYo

It won't show the full height in most cases, but it will show the bottom of the image.

Or you use `background-size: contain` and (in this particular situation) combine it with a white background color

EDIT: White won't work, I didn't look close enough. Here's approximately what I mean, but it's not really satisfying, since there isn't just *one* color at the border of the image:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZZpMX

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size` with `100%` height and width.

Remove

```
background-size:cover;
```

Replace with:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: this will distort the image (i.e. its width/height proportions)